# Displaying a message if ajaxform successfull or failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I would like to upload a file without refreshing all the page. I know that uploading does not support classic ajax form. The trick is to use a classic form and to ajaxify it.

Here is my view:

```
@model .....
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "uploadform" }))
{            
    <div class="editor-label">              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)            </div>  
    <div class="editor-field">              <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />     </div>

    <button type="submit"> 
        <span>Upload</span> 
    </button>   
}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $('#uploadform').ajaxForm(function () {
        alert("Thank you for your comment!");
    });     
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Add code here...
        return RedirectToAction("EditProject");
    }
```

When I submit a file, the action in the controller receive the information. BUT next nothing happened. The message 'Thank you for your comment!' is never displayed. **I would like to display a message if the upload is successful of failed.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The UploadImage method in your Controller redirects to another action. You should return JSON with a message to be displayed.

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   //processing code...

   return Json(new { message = "Thank you..." }); 
}
```

And then in the View just alert the returned message.

Comment: Do we always had to return a Json object with an ajax form? In fact the RedirectToAction("EditProject") is the same page.

Comment: Shouldn't you just refer to the Page instead then: return View();

Comment: And how can I just alert the returned message in the view?  I try $('#uploadform').ajaxForm(function (message) { alert(message); }); This doesn't work.